# Appending on javascript with onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm appending some html codes on javascript. I'm also binding an onclick to it. The problem is, I'm getting a javascript error each time I press onclick. I'm passing a string to the function onclick. Here's a clearer view.

```
var propertyTypeDdlValues = "";

propertyTypeDdlValues += "<li onclick='selectPropertyType('Condominium/Studio')'>Condominium/Studio</li>"; 

$("#propertyTypeDdl").html(propertyTypeDdlValues);
```

This is my selectPropertyType

```
function selectPropertyType(cattype){
    $("#propertyType").text(cattype);
    $("#hdnPropertyType").val(cattype);
}
```

I keep on having this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

I think the problem is how I wrap strings around (" "). What made me say this? Because when I try to just use a simple function like this:

```
propertyTypeDdlValues += "<li onclick='displayMessage()'>Condominium/Studio</li>"; 

function displayMessage(){
    alert("Message");
}
```

It goes through the function and the alert message is being displayed.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: "I'm passing a string to the function onclick" - bad idea.

Comment: can u create a js fiddle or post ur html code too

Comment: Try adding a \ before and after the quotes of `Condominium/Studio`.

Comment: @iBlue no need to use txtspk hre. You've got 300 characters per comment - more than enough

Comment: @JanDvorak aye aye sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjLZg/1/)

```
$(function () {  

     $("#propertyTypeDdl").append("<li onclick=
      selectPropertyType('Condominium/Studio')>Condominium/Studio</li>");

     $("#propertyTypeDdl").append("<li onclick=
      'displayMessage()'>Condominium/Studio</li>");
});

function selectPropertyType(cattype) {
    $("#propertyType").val(cattype);
}

function displayMessage() {
    alert("Message");
}
```

Comment: After reading all answers. This one is the most efficient and effective. It's simple and straightforward. I can't believe I just have to remove " ' " wrapping around onclick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to store that string in a variable and passing that into the function. But I guess some one else will give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your **propertyTypeDdlValues** to

```
propertyTypeDdlValues += 
   "<li onclick='selectPropertyType('\'Condominium/Studio\'')'>
      Condominium/Studio
   </li>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery.
So why not:

```
foreach(thing in listOfThings) {
    var li = $('<li>' + thig.name + '</li>');
    li.click(function(e) {
        selectPropertyType($(this).html());
    });

    $("#propertyTypeDdl").append(li);
}
```

It's a lot cleaner.

Friendly advice: never ever use HTML on/whatever events again :)

Answer (score 0):

Your original string

```
"<li onclick='selectPropertyType('Condominium/Studio')'>Condominium/Studio</li>"
```

Gets parsed as this HTML:

```
<li onclick='selectPropertyType('Condominium/Studio')'>Condominium/Studio</li>
```

The onclick atrribute ends just after the left bracket, leading to invalid javascript. Since you have three levels of nesting, you'll need to escape your quotes:

```
"<li onclick='selectPropertyType(\'Condominium/Studio\')'>Condominium/Studio</li>"
```

or

```
"<li onclick='selectPropertyType(\"Condominium/Studio\")'>Condominium/Studio</li>"
```

but it is better to avoid pieces of javascript code as strings (and, since you're using jQuery, avoid `onclick` attributes altogether), and create an element and set its click handler to a function. This will also avoid the need to nest string literals:

```
var $li = $("<li>").text('Condominium/Studio').click(function(){
  selectPropertyType('Condominium/Studio')
});

$propertyTypeDdlValues = $propertyTypeDdlValues.add($li)
```